# Java - toString doesn't print array correctly

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

Java question.

I wanted to print out an array with the to String method,
but all I get is this:

```
fifo.Fifo@2a139a55
fifo.Fifo@15db9742
```

I know that this points to the point where the arrays are saved,
but how can I actually print out the arrays with the toStinr method?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fifo {

    private ArrayList <Object> list;

    public Fifo() {
        this.list = new ArrayList <Object>();
    }

    public void push(Object obj) {
        list.add(obj);
    }

    public ArrayList getList() {
        return this.list;
    }

    public Object pull() {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("leer");
            return null;
        }
        Object o = list.get(0);
        list.remove(0);
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (o.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
            Fifo other = (Fifo) o;
            ArrayList otherList = other.getList();

            if (otherList.size() == this.getList().size()) {
                boolean sameObjects = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    if (!list.get(i).equals(otherList.get(i))) {
                        sameObjects = false;
                    }
                }
                if (sameObjects)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Fifo clone() {
        Fifo cloneObj = new Fifo();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.list.size(); i++) {
            cloneObj.push(this.list.get(i));
        }
        return cloneObj;
    }
}
```

This is the seperate method for testing:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Aufgabe {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Fifo test = new Fifo();
        Fifo test2;

        test.push(1234);
        test.push("Hallo");
        test.push(5678);
        test.push("du da");

        test.pull();

        System.out.println(test.toString());
        test2=test.clone();
        System.out.println(test2.toString());
        System.out.println(test2.equals(test));
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't tag the question with a language. I assume this is Java?

Comment: Have you overriden toString()-method in your Fifo-class?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: No. It uses the java standart toString method.

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString()`

Comment: @marvin Don't make your question meaningless to future readers by deleting the code that the question is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're not using an array, you're using an `ArrayList` - this is an implemention of [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) in Java.

Secondly, you're not printing out the array list, you're printing the object containing it - an instance of `Foo`.

```
Fifo test = new Fifo();
// do stuff
System.out.println(test.toString());
```

If you just want to print out the list, you need to use

```
Fifo test = new Fifo();
// do stuff
System.out.println(test.getList());
```

A nicer solution would be to override `toString` in your Foo class.

```
public class Foo {
  // everything you already have

  public String toString() {
    // you can format this however you want
    return "Contents of my list: " + list;
  }
}
```

This method will then be automatically called when you pass the object to `System.out.println`.

```
Foo test = new Foo();
// do stuff
System.out.println(test);
```

will result in `Contents of my list: [a, b, c]` (where `a, b, c` is actually whatever you have in your list).

**Supplementary info**
When you're using System.out.println in Java, remember:

- primitives will be printed as they are, e.g. `System.out.println(1)` will print `1` and `System.out.println(false)` will print `false`.
- Object instances (i.e. non-primitives) will have the `toString()` method called by `println`.
- The default `toString` of an object is `className@hashCode`.
- The default `toString` of a one-dimensional array is `[LclassName@hashCode`.  Additional dimensions will result in an additional `[` at the begining of the string.

Comment: Best answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are objects which do not override the `toString()` method, so, as you noted, you'll get the default implementation which contains the class name and the [default] hashCode(). To "properly" convert an array to a string, you could use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-):

```
MyObject[] array = ...;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
Arrays.toString(yourArray);
```

---

What toString will print you for an array will contain the hashcode, type of the elements of the array so not really what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

override the `Object.toString()` and give your implementation that will work fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks, I am new to this forum and I am understanding bit by bit..

Comment: @Phani actually that is (at least part of) the correct answer, so a comment would be inappropriate

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned use Arrays.toString() method.

Coming to

```
fifo.Fifo@2a139a55
fifo.Fifo@15db9742
```

This is how `toString()` method defined in Object class works. It prints a string of the following format:

```
ClassName@HexadecimalOfHashCode
```

This is the default implementation defined in the Object class. Since your FIFO class does not override `toString()` method, invocation of `toString()` on your FIFO objects, calls the `toString()` method in Object class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `toString()` *in your `Fifo` class* to print something useful. Perhaps something like this would be suitable:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Fifo" + list.toString();
}
```

(This will give you something like `Fifo[element1, element2]`.)